# How to convert a pandas dataframe column from string to an array of floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe where a column is an array of floats. When I am reading the csv file as a pandas dataframe, the particular column is recognized as a string as follows:

```
'[4816.0, 20422.0, 2015.0, 2020.0, 2025.0, 5799.0, 2000.0, 1996.0, 3949.0, 3488.0]', 
'[13047.0, 7388.0, 16437.0, 2096.0, 13618.0, 2000.0, 1996.0, 23828.0, 6466.0, 1996.0]',....
```

I want to convert this long character string into an array of floats like this:

```
[4816.0, 20422.0, 2015.0, 2020.0, 2025.0, 5799.0, 2000.0, 1996.0, 3949.0, 3488.0],
[13047.0, 7388.0, 16437.0, 2096.0, 13618.0, 2000.0, 1996.0, 23828.0, 6466.0, 1996.0],...
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change data type of columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: `astype` is not general purpose deserialization of strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, it would be best to read the csv correctly (as a list of floats) rather than casting them from the strings.  You can however use `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` to cast this to a list of floats:

```
from ast import literal_eval    
df["a"] = df["a"].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am curious to know how to read the particular of the csv file as a list of floats while reading the csv file with multiple columns of different data types.